# Whether to and how to MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Hi there I have read many articles on MVVM from MSDN.

I have understood it at least technically but I dont know whether to say I understood it or not as a design pattern.

Since while imagining MVVM in my scenario, my thinking gets stuck somewhere. So please help to decide whether to MVVM or not and if Yes how to.

I have a **layout** containing some shapes and button. I am allowing user to customize them (atleast color and font). I am thinking to store the customizable property values as XML and one-way bind them to XmlDataSource. Each time user launches the app the color/font will be retrieved from Xml file.

When user clicks one of the component of the layout say button, a UI to customize button will be populated (say color picker and font chooser). Now user may select change the color/font. So here, I think I should generate customization UI, bind it (**dynamically through the code?**) to the ViewModel and ViewModel will contain methods to manipulate Xml (which will be Model XmlDataProvider).

**However all articles I read online talks about object ViewModel (and connecting it to the UI through many interfaces), but doesnt talk about how that ViewModel binds to the underlying data source be it XML or SQL.**

So from layout to Xml file - there will be one way binding and from Customization UI to Xml file, there will be ViewModel in between.

**Will any changes made from Customization UI will be reflected on layout immediately?** Is this binding architecture right? Is this what followed in such scenarios? Am I messing with the MVVM design concept. Should this be different way? or Should I not go to MVVM? Please help.

I put hard efforts in learning all big-big articles, I understood them quite well, but :(. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MVVM is perfect for what you are trying to do, but remember that the goal of MVVM is to provide abstraction at the UI-level.  It separates UI display logic from the logic that acquires and transforms the data.

It is fine to load configuration stuff from XML, but as far as your view is concerned, it just needs to know what property on your ViewModel to bind to.  As your ViewModel updates that property (by querying the Model), the UI will automatically change without you having to do anything.

How your ViewModel gets the data is entirely up to you.  This is where the Model comes in.  Your model acquires the data that will be used by the ViewModel.  This isn't a hard rule, but your Model will either be a service or another class in your solution that fetches the data.  The service or class provide data access methods for querying the data from a data source.  The model can have an interface in front of it so it can be interchanged if you need to work at that level.

If you are using Silverlight, most likely the data will come from a call to a web service on the server.  If you are using WPF, you might have a Data layer that pulls directly from the XML file or a database.  The ViewModel is just responsible for providing the glue between your view and data.  I just wouldn't put query logic directly in the ViewModel.  I would have that in a separate data layer.

In my humble opinion, many of the MVVM advocates like to overcomplicate the pattern.  They wrap everything in interfaces and write large frameworks to implement MVVM.  These tools have a place, but I believe one must tread carefully not to overcomplicate a solution that could be solved with a much simpler implementation.  For a basic application, simply having a ViewModel class that the view directly binds too should be sufficient.

Comment: pretty good answer, but you do not mention the Model anywhere - care to elaborate?

Comment: If the view model interacts directly with the data source, how is that any different to having the view's code behind do so? This is not "over-architecting" - it's fundamental separation of concerns.

Comment: @KentBoogaart - I updated my description to put more detail around the purpose of the model.

Comment: @KentBoogaart - By "over-architecting" I'm not saying there isn't a place for a complete separation of concerns.  What I'm saying is that I've seen people go crazy with the MVVM pattern that extends way beyond the "fundamental separation of concerns" so that anyone trying to maintain the UI simply can't anymore without fully understanding a 3rd party framework with all its ins and outs.  When it gets to that points, the advantages of separation have been lost.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think if you are working with WPF you should be using MVVM

The way the XAML works with a `DataContext` means that your entire application can be written in the code classes, and the XAML is simply a pretty UI layer that sits on top of your classes to provide a user-friendly interface. It makes the code easy to work with and maintain.

Perhaps you'd be interested in a [smaller and simpler MVVM example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) that I have posted on my blog

Answer (score 1):

> However all articles I read online talks about object ViewModel (and
>   connecting it to the UI through many interfaces), but doesnt talk
>   about how that ViewModel binds to the underlying data source be it XML
>   or SQL.

The view model should not concern itself with how the data is stored. It is, after all, merely an extension of the view. It is separated primarily for testability and maintainability.

View models should rely on services to work with data. Typically you would define an interface for each service and have the view model work against the interface. Then, you can provide mock implementations when unit testing your view models.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Caliburn Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/), it makes complex screen composition a pretty simple task.  [Here](http://vimeo.com/16975621) is a video of the HelloScreens example the comes with the source.  [Media Owl](http://mediaowl.codeplex.com/) is another excellent example.

MVVM doesn't care where the data is coming from.  One thing I personally do is create display models for my views.  I don't like binding views directly to my data model.  I like to work from the view backwards.  Caliburn Micro makes that easy as it supports design time data that work with its conventions.

Once the view is laid out with design data, then I consume the sources that provide the model and map whats needed to my display models.